# AngularJS directive watch parent size change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

## Problem

I have a simple directive that executes sizing updates on a particular element.  This watches the window size and makes adjustments accordingly.

```
MyApp.directive('resizeTest', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var w = angular.element($window);
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() };
      }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        // resizing happens here
      }, true);
      w.bind('resize', function() { scope.$apply(); });
    }
  };
}]);
```

This works just fine.

It just so happens that inside of the `div` tag that is associated with, I have a child `div`.  When the parent is resized, I want to make positioning alterations on the child element.  However, I cannot get the trigger to fire.

This gets called at startup, but does not get triggered when the element is resized or the window changes:

```
MyApp.directive('centerVertical', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.css({border: '1px solid #0000FF'});
      scope.$watch('data.overlaytype', function() {
        $window.setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('I am:      ' + element.width() + 'x' + element.height());
          console.log('Parent is: ' + element.parent().width() + 'x' + element.parent().height());
        }, 1);
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

What type of binding or watch configuration should I be using to check for resizing of the parent element?

## Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/rcy63v7t/1/

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: I'll try and set one up.  I haven't done one of those for AngularJS yet, so it will be a good experience.

Comment: Fiddle added.  I noted that if I commented out the second directive, the first one works again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value `data.overlaytype` you are observing in the `centerVertical` directive is not on the `scope` so the resulting value is `undefined` and this value never changes that's why you dont get the listener executed.
To check if the size of the parent element changed you can check it in the $watch function like this:

```
scope.$watch(
    function () { 
        return {
           width: element.parent().width(),
           height: element.parent().height(),
        }
   },
   function () {}, //listener 
   true //deep watch
);
```

Moreover remember, when you want to use an already existing module you can't call it like this `angular.module('myModule', [])` because this mean creating new module. You have to just pass the module name `angular.module('myModule')`, which is second thing why your code didn't work.

Comment: This does not work as expected - when resizing the window/browser the $watch is not called.

Comment: This works, though the watch is only triggered on a digest.

Comment: @eln00b Also, don't forget that Angular fires each watch on registration time (!), so if you really want it to fire **only** on resize event, in your watch handler add: "if (newValue === oldValue) {return;}" to prevent the registration time firing.